# Producing a printable calendar with Python

Tags: python, image, pdf, calendar

How can I produce a printable PDF file (US letter sized) such that each page represents a month and is partitioned such that each day of the month gets a box of equal size? What if I want to skip weekends and just display weekdays?

**What Python modules would I use to accomplish the following?**:

1. Producing an image with the resolution of a US letter
2. Iterating through each day of the month with the option to skip specific days (e.g., all weekends)
3. Partitioning the image such that each day of the month is listed in a box of fixed size
4. Repeating steps 2-3 for all months in a given year
5. Producing a pdf as the output

Comment: Lucky for you there's a whole module for calculating calendars: http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of questions here, questions about working with calendars, and separately about high resolution images.  Each one should be a separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it with 3 packages.  'Reportlab' for producing the pdf, 'calendar' for getting the month as lists of lists, and python binding for 'Ghostscript' to transform the pdf produced into a png.

You would start by getting the data from the calendar package, using Reportlab to produce a page of US letter size.  The table can be manipulated to have a grid, have each cell a box of the same size and alter the text font, size, and alignment.

You could leave it at that if you just want a pdf, or you can convert this pdf into a image using Ghostscript python bindings.  Or if you like you can just run 'Ghostscript' using system('gs ...').  Also Ghostscript must be installed for the python 'Ghostscript' package to work.

If you want to filter out all weekends then you can use good old fashioned list manipulation on the calendar data for that.

Here is a example of how you could produce the pdf.  I'm not going to do a whole year just a single month, and I'm not going to bother filtering out the zeros.

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing

import calendar

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('calendar.pdf', pagesize=letter)

cal = [['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']]
cal.extend(calendar.monthcalendar(2011,9))


table = Table(cal, 7*[inch], len(cal) * [inch])

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
        ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8),
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.green),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
    ]))

#create the pdf with this
doc.build([table])
```

If you want another page add PageBreak() followed by the next calendar to the list passed to doc.build(). PageBreak is part of reportlab.platypus.

And to convert the pdf to png

```
import ghostscript

args = ['gs', #it seems not to matter what is put in 1st position
        '-dSAFER',
        '-dBATCH',
        '-dNOPAUSE',
        '-sDEVICE=png16m',
        '-r100',
        '-sOutputFile=calendar.png',
        'calendar.pdf']

ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

Both reportlab and ghostscript packages are available through the use of pip.  I created the above in a 'virtualenv' environment.

ReportLab
http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/

Ghostscript python bindings
https://bitbucket.org/htgoebel/python-ghostscript

calendar is part of the standard python library.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who wanders in off Google, a fellow named Bill Mill wrote a <strike>[public domain module](http://billmill.org/calendar)</strike> that makes generating a calendar using reportlab as simple as this example text.

```
from pdf_calendar import createCalendar
#create a December, 2005 PDF
c = createCalendar(12, 2005, filename="blog_calendar.pdf")
#now add January, 2006 to the end
createCalendar(1, 2006, canvas=c)
c.save()
```

There's also sample output at the link I provided and, while it's simple and spartan, it looks decent (similar to what you get out of things like the "make calendar" script for Scribus) and would make an excellent starting point for future enhancements.

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Create a PDF calendar.

This script requires Python and Reportlab
( http://reportlab.org/rl_toolkit.html ). Tested only with Python 2.4 and
Reportlab 1.2.

See bottom of file for an example of usage. No command-line interface has been
added, but it would be trivial to do so. Furthermore, this script is pretty
hacky, and could use some refactoring, but it works for what it's intended
to do.

Created by Bill Mill on 11/16/05, this script is in the public domain. There
are no express warranties, so if you mess stuff up with this script, it's not
my fault.

If you have questions or comments or bugfixes or flames, please drop me a line 
at bill.mill@gmail.com .
"""
from reportlab.lib import pagesizes
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
import calendar, time, datetime
from math import floor

NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
SIZE = pagesizes.landscape(pagesizes.letter)

class NoCanvasError(Exception): pass

def nonzero(row):
    return len([x for x in row if x!=0])

def createCalendar(month, year=NOW.year, canvas=None, filename=None, \
                   size=SIZE):
    """
    Create a one-month pdf calendar, and return the canvas
    
    month: can be an integer (1=Jan, 12=Dec) or a month abbreviation (Jan, Feb,
            etc.
    year: year in which month falls. Defaults to current year.
    canvas: you may pass in a canvas to add a calendar page to the end.
    filename: String containing the file to write the calendar to
    size: size, in points of the canvas to write on
    """
    if type(month) == type(''):
        month = time.strptime(month, "%b")[1]
    if canvas is None and filename is not None:
        canvas = Canvas(filename, size)
    elif canvas is None and filename is None:
        raise NoCanvasError
    monthname = time.strftime("%B", time.strptime(str(month), "%m"))
    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)

    width, height = size

    #draw the month title
    title = monthname + ' ' + str(year)
    canvas.drawCentredString(width / 2, height - 27, title)
    height = height - 40

    #margins
    wmar, hmar = width/50, height/50

    #set up constants
    width, height = width - (2*wmar), height - (2*hmar)
    rows, cols = len(cal), 7
    lastweek = nonzero(cal[-1])
    firstweek = nonzero(cal[0])
    weeks = len(cal)
    rowheight = floor(height / rows)
    boxwidth = floor(width/7)

    #draw the bottom line
    canvas.line(wmar, hmar, wmar+(boxwidth*lastweek), hmar)
    #now, for all complete rows, draw the bottom line
    for row in range(1, len(cal[1:-1]) + 1):
        y = hmar + (row * rowheight)
        canvas.line(wmar, y, wmar + (boxwidth * 7), y)
    #now draw the top line of the first full row
    y = hmar + ((rows-1) * rowheight)
    canvas.line(wmar, y, wmar + (boxwidth * 7), y)
    #and, then the top line of the first row
    startx = wmar + (boxwidth * (7-firstweek))
    endx = startx + (boxwidth * firstweek)
    y = y + rowheight
    canvas.line(startx, y, endx, y)

    #now draw the vert lines
    for col in range(8):
        #1 = don't draw line to first or last; 0 = do draw
        last, first = 1, 1
        if col <= lastweek: last = 0
        if col >= 7 - firstweek: first = 0
        x = wmar + (col * boxwidth)
        starty = hmar + (last * rowheight)
        endy = hmar + (rows * rowheight) - (first * rowheight)
        canvas.line(x, starty, x, endy)

    #now fill in the day numbers and any data
    x = wmar + 6
    y = hmar + (rows * rowheight) - 15
    for week in cal:
        for day in week:
            if day:
                canvas.drawString(x, y, str(day))
            x = x + boxwidth
        y = y - rowheight
        x = wmar + 6
    
    #finish this page
    canvas.showPage()

    return canvas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create a December, 2005 PDF
    c = createCalendar(12, 2005, filename="blog_calendar.pdf")
    #now add January, 2006 to the end
    createCalendar(1, 2006, canvas=c)
    c.save()
```

**EDIT 2017-11-25:** I had to refactor this for my own use, so I thought I'd share it here. The newest version will always be [in this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ssokolow/7eace74070778abe637bcd56b105e0d4) but, below, I'm including the last revision before it gained a dependency on PyEphem for calculating things like moon phases:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Generate a printable calendar in PDF format, suitable for embedding
into another document.

Tested with Python 2.7 and 3.8.


Dependencies:
- Python
- Reportlab

Resources Used:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37443801/435253
  (Originally present at http://billmill.org/calendar )
- https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Originally created by Bill Mill on 11/16/05, this script is in the public
domain. There are no express warranties, so if you mess stuff up with this
script, it's not my fault.

Refactored and improved 2017-11-23 by Stephan Sokolow (http://ssokolow.com/).

TODO:
- Implement diagonal/overlapped cells for months which touch six weeks to avoid
  wasting space on six rows.
"""

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        with_statement, unicode_literals)

__author__ = "Bill Mill; Stephan Sokolow (deitarion/SSokolow)"
__license__ = "CC0-1.0"  # https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

import calendar, collections, datetime
from contextlib import contextmanager

from reportlab.lib import pagesizes
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

# Supporting languages like French should be as simple as editing this
ORDINALS = {
    1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd',
    21: 'st', 22: 'nd', 23: 'rd',
    31: 'st',
    None: 'th'}

# Something to help make code more readable
Font = collections.namedtuple('Font', ['name', 'size'])
Geom = collections.namedtuple('Geom', ['x', 'y', 'width', 'height'])
Size = collections.namedtuple('Size', ['width', 'height'])


@contextmanager
def save_state(canvas):
    """Simple context manager to tidy up saving and restoring canvas state"""
    canvas.saveState()
    yield
    canvas.restoreState()


def add_calendar_page(canvas, rect, datetime_obj, cell_cb,
                      first_weekday=calendar.SUNDAY):
    """Create a one-month pdf calendar, and return the canvas

    @param rect: A C{Geom} or 4-item iterable of floats defining the shape of
        the calendar in points with any margins already applied.
    @param datetime_obj: A Python C{datetime} object specifying the month
        the calendar should represent.
    @param cell_cb: A callback taking (canvas, day, rect, font) as arguments
        which will be called to render each cell.
        (C{day} will be 0 for empty cells.)

    @type canvas: C{reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas}
    @type rect: C{Geom}
    @type cell_cb: C{function(Canvas, int, Geom, Font)}
    """
    calendar.setfirstweekday(first_weekday)
    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(datetime_obj.year, datetime_obj.month)
    rect = Geom(*rect)

    # set up constants
    scale_factor = min(rect.width, rect.height)
    line_width = scale_factor * 0.0025
    font = Font('Helvetica', scale_factor * 0.028)
    rows = len(cal)

    # Leave room for the stroke width around the outermost cells
    rect = Geom(rect.x + line_width,
                rect.y + line_width,
                rect.width - (line_width * 2),
                rect.height - (line_width * 2))
    cellsize = Size(rect.width / 7, rect.height / rows)

    # now fill in the day numbers and any data
    for row, week in enumerate(cal):
        for col, day in enumerate(week):
            # Give each call to cell_cb a known canvas state
            with save_state(canvas):

                # Set reasonable default drawing parameters
                canvas.setFont(*font)
                canvas.setLineWidth(line_width)

                cell_cb(canvas, day, Geom(
                    x=rect.x + (cellsize.width * col),
                    y=rect.y + ((rows - row) * cellsize.height),
                    width=cellsize.width, height=cellsize.height),
                    font, scale_factor)

    # finish this page
    canvas.showPage()
    return canvas


def draw_cell(canvas, day, rect, font, scale_factor):
    """Draw a calendar cell with the given characteristics

    @param day: The date in the range 0 to 31.
    @param rect: A Geom(x, y, width, height) tuple defining the shape of the
        cell in points.
    @param scale_factor: A number which can be used to calculate sizes which
        will remain proportional to the size of the entire calendar.
        (Currently the length of the shortest side of the full calendar)

    @type rect: C{Geom}
    @type font: C{Font}
    @type scale_factor: C{float}
    """
    # Skip drawing cells that don't correspond to a date in this month
    if not day:
        return

    margin = Size(font.size * 0.5, font.size * 1.3)

    # Draw the cell border
    canvas.rect(rect.x, rect.y - rect.height, rect.width, rect.height)

    day = str(day)
    ordinal_str = ORDINALS.get(int(day), ORDINALS[None])

    # Draw the number
    text_x = rect.x + margin.width
    text_y = rect.y - margin.height
    canvas.drawString(text_x, text_y, day)

    # Draw the lifted ordinal number suffix
    number_width = canvas.stringWidth(day, font.name, font.size)
    canvas.drawString(text_x + number_width,
                      text_y + (margin.height * 0.1),
                      ordinal_str)


def generate_pdf(datetime_obj, outfile, size, first_weekday=calendar.SUNDAY):
    """Helper to apply add_calendar_page to save a ready-to-print file to disk.

    @param datetime_obj: A Python C{datetime} object specifying the month
        the calendar should represent.
    @param outfile: The path to which to write the PDF file.
    @param size: A (width, height) tuple (specified in points) representing
        the target page size.
    """
    size = Size(*size)
    canvas = Canvas(outfile, size)

    # margins
    wmar, hmar = size.width / 50, size.height / 50
    size = Size(size.width - (2 * wmar), size.height - (2 * hmar))

    add_calendar_page(canvas,
                      Geom(wmar, hmar, size.width, size.height),
                      datetime_obj, draw_cell, first_weekday).save()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_pdf(datetime.datetime.now(), 'calendar.pdf',
                 pagesizes.landscape(pagesizes.letter))
```

The refactored code has the following advantages:

- The calendar drawing function doesn't draw anything other than the marginless cells themselves, so it's useful for embedding the output into larger creations.
- The code to draw individual cells has been factored out into a callback which receives a freshly-reset canvas state each time.
- It's all nicely documented now. (Admittedly, in ePydoc markup I haven't run through ePyDoc yet)
- Code to draw top-aligned ordinal suffixes on numbers
- PEP-8 compliant code style and proper metadata.

**UPDATE 2021-09-30:** Here's what the `calendar.pdf` generated by that last code block looks like when viewed in Okular 1.9.3 at 75%:

[image: example calendar]

(Ignore the varying line widths. That's just an Okular 1.9.3 rendering bug that shows up at certain zoom levels.)

Comment: Great answer, better than accepted one. I've attached the full in case the linked site isn't available.

Comment: I'd love to see example output here!

Comment: @jvriesem Done. Thanks for reminding me that I hadn't put a preview up.

Comment: FYI, I've updated this for Python 3 in https://github.com/gjoseph92/calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar roblem a while back - I used the excellent pcal utility.  It's not python but even as a python bigot I found severe limitations getting reliable printable PDFs from python - my LaTeX was not good enough

http://www.itmanagerscookbook.com/Workstation/power-user/calendar.html

Comment: Can this link be updated?